# Issues with Move Hub and Controller: first connected device works, but not both

Tags: powered-up, remote-control

I'm having issues with the move hub 88006, the controller 88010 and the Powered Up app.

The issue is the same on multiple devices.

Basically, whatever I connect via Bluetooth first is what works, but I can't get them both to work.

If I connect the hub first, I can program the hub and it works fine, but the controller block doesn't work (any button presses don't appear to register)

If I connect the remote first, the button presses on the remote register, but the hub doesn't react.

They both appear to be connected in the Bluetooth menu.

I have unpaired and re-paired multiple times, changed batteries, and tried my phone and tablet and the issue is the same.

Does anyone have any ideas?